# how could I figure out RAM consumption of services?

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, services

I'm using Windows 7 SP1. Recently I feel it runs slower and slower. The applications do not consume much RAM, so I guess some services do. How can I see the memory consumption by each service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading and running free Process Explorer utility from Sysinternals / Microsoft available at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx